# CSS - background color set, but still transparent

Tags: css

On [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/mrbarval/mr-barval-is/), when the view port is around 680 pixels wide in Mozilla Firefox responsive design view, the top navigation menu collapses into a 'burger'.

When you open the menu, the menu's background is transparent, meaning you see the page content underneath the LI elements.

I added CSS: `.menu, #menu-primary-menu, #mainnav .menu > ul > li {background-color: #FFF;}`, and the CSS is recognized, and loaded, but still, I can see through the `LI`, `UL.menu` to the content underneath.

I'm not sure what code to include in my question; it is a complicated set up, and I can't see in Firebug what is causing the transparency of the `LI`, `UL.menu` elements. I hope you can use the live test page to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `z-index: 9;` to the `li`.

```
#mainnav .menu > ul > li {
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 9;
}
```

> *The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.*